# Postgresql using same parameter more than

Tags: postgresql

I created a function. I want to use same parameter different place in a query. When I run query normally I get query result is 31 msec. When I use parameter in function that doesnt return a result. The query is just running. How can I solve?

The query result is 31 msec.

```
        SELECT t2.id, t2.sk, t2.sk_code, t2.yl,
        st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) AS mf, t2.rc::INTEGER
        FROM public.rc t2
        where st_intersects(st_buffer(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813), 4326), 500000),400),t2.geom)= true and
        st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) =
        (SELECT  distinct  st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) from
        public.rc t2  where st_intersects(st_buffer(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813), 4326), 500000),400),t2.geom)
        =true
        group by st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813), 4326), 500000), t2.geom)
        ORDER BY st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) ASC
        limit 1 )
        ORDER BY yl asc ,st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) ASC;
```

The function can not return anything just running.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getplaces(
  IN latx double precision,
  IN lngx double precision,
  OUT id integer,
  OUT sk character varying,
  OUT sk_code double precision,
  OUT yl double precision,
  OUT mf double precision,
  OUT rc integer)
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
    SELECT t2.id, t2.sk, t2.sk_code, t2.yl,
        st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) AS mf, t2.rc::INTEGER
    FROM  public.rc t2
        where st_intersects(st_buffer(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx), 4326), 500000),400),t2.geom)= true and
        st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) =
        (SELECT  distinct  st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) from
        public.rc t2  where st_intersects(st_buffer(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx), 4326), 500000),400),t2.geom)
        =true
        group by st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx), 4326), 500000), t2.geom)
        ORDER BY st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) ASC
        limit 1 )
        ORDER BY yl asc ,st_distance(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_point(getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx), 4326), 500000), t2.geom) ASC;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
COST 1000
ROWS 1000;
```

Comment: Figure out the execution plans for both queries. For the query with parameters, create a prepared statement with parameters using `PREPARE` and `EXPLAIN` the `EXECUTE` six times until you see `$1` appear in the plan. If the latter plan actually is worse, use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I used 
EXPLAIN Select  * from developer.getplaces(40.944709258659690,29.160144542327885)  The result is "Function Scan on getplaces  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=162)"

Comment: Also I used execute format in query didnt change anything

Comment: I have explained it in an answer - a comment is too short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to figure out how the execution plans are different.

First, run

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT t2.id, ...;
```

using the query with the constants that runs “fast”.

The harder part is to figure out the execution plan for the query inside the function. You can use prepared statements to do that:

```
PREPARE stmt(double precision, double precision) AS
SELECT t2.id, t2.sk, ...
   ... st_point($1, $2) ...;
```

Just replace all places where a function parameter appears with `$1` or `$2`.

Then run:

```
EXPLAIN EXECUTE stmt(28.862966895103455, 41.02119524147813);
```

You should get a plan that contains `$1` and `$2` rather than the parameter values.

It would be nice if you could run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` here, but if the execution time is too long, that is not an option.

Then compare the execution plans and see what is different in the second one. Maybe you can improve the statement so that it does what you want more efficiently.

If you cannot find a solution that way, you can resort to using a dynamic SQL statement in a PL/pgSQL function. That should have the same execution plan as your first statement:

```
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      'SELECT t2.id, t2.sk, ...
         ...st_point($1, $2) ...'
      USING getplaces.lngx, getplaces.latx;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.